# Japanese text display from the webservice response

Tags: utf8-decode

I am trying to fetch Japanese text from an API.

The API is responding properly with Japanese text if tested individually. However, when I add it in my application, I am getting some junk data instead of Japanese text.

I am also adding `charset=utf-8` to the header.

Please help me convert that junk data to proper Japanese text.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem in the way you are fetching that text (if you're getting junk, it may be encoded already).

You can try to use something similar to [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) in your application (depending on the language you are using) and be sure to use [similar functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) when you are performing operations in that text.